# Color a tetrahedron in three.js

Tags: three.js

In three.js, I'm trying to draw a tetrahedron using `THREE.TetrahedronGeometry` where each face is a different color. When I use MeshNormalMaterial, each vertex has a different color but the faces are color gradients between the vertexes. This works for a BoxGeometry, but not for TetrahedronGeometry.

I tried using PhongMaterial with `shading: THREE.FlatShading` but that just gives me black or white faces.

I tried writing my own ShaderMaterial and in the fragment material, I color using the normal vector, but that also gets the gradient affect.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can't see it...

Comment: same question here (with answer) : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71547975/how-to-render-a-tetrahedron-with-different-texture-on-each-face-using-three-js/71548718?noredirect=1#comment126456642_71548718

Answer (score 0):

For versions of three.js prior to r125*, this is how you do it:

```
var geo = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry(sphereRadius, 0);
for ( var i = 0; i < geo.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    geo.faces[ i ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
}

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
})
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geo, material );
```

So  you need THREE.FlatShader, THREE.VertexColors, and then you need to assign the face colors.

For later versions, see [how to render a tetrahedron with different texture on each face (using three.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71547975/how-to-render-a-tetrahedron-with-different-texture-on-each-face-using-three-js?noredirect=1#comment126454548_71547975).

* [THREE.Geometry will be removed from core with r125](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401)